# PathMaps config for xdebug and Atom

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug, atom-editor

I am trying to setup php-debug in the Atom editor.

Following the instructions everything seems to be fine but I don't know what to write in the config.cson.

```
"php-debug":
{
ServerPort: 9000
PathMaps: [
  "remotepath;localpath"
  "/base/path/on/remote/system;C:\\base\\path\\on\\local\\system"
]
}
```

I am working on a Symfony 3 project locally (in Ubuntu). The code is in `/var/www/myprojectfolder` and I don't get what I am supposed to write in the `pathMaps` field to make it work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Either the same path for both local and remote .. or omit it completely (as you do not need the path mapping -- it's local already; unless, if you have symbolic links in the path .. they might be required).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne ! It works perfectly. Could you add it as an answer so I can accept it?